# Possible to make something like macros in c, but in bash?

Tags: bash

I am pretty new to bash cripting, and have run into the following problem:

I am writing test cases in Bash, defined as functions which should return 1 in case of failure. These test cases could use some sort of macro, (or alias?) which takes a command as an argument, evaluates its results, and returns 1 (from the test case) if a failure occurs.

My current solution is a function which takes a command as an argument, and returns 0 or 1 depending on its result. The problem here is that each time this function is used in a test case, an if statement is needed to check its return value, and then return from the test case if there was an error. I would rather just have a one-line "assertion" of some sort. Some way to return a value "two levels up" from a function, or a c-style macro which makes a preprocessor insert the if statement after the result automatically could solve my isse, but I haven't found anything similar.

Is this even possible, or perhaps just bad practice?

A quick example of what I'm after:

```
function a_test_case{
    return_1_if_prints_foo "echo foo" #should return 1 from a_test_case
    ...
}
```

which should have the same result as

```
function a_test_case{
    prints_foo "echo foo"
    if [ $? = 1 ]; then
        return 1
    fi
    ...
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: When a function returns a value, it will be returned as `$?`. I see from your example that you are just returning `$?` from function. So, I think that this function is redundant...

Comment: I was a bit unclear, but the test case is supposed to do other things after the if statement. In this case, it should not return if $? is 0, just keep running.

Comment: Turns out the test framework Im using starts test cases as sub shells, which makes `exit` sort of act as a multi-level return which I can use in the inner function. My question still stands though (interesting in cases where eg tests are not subshells).

Answer (score 0):

> Is this even possible, or perhaps just bad practice?

Returning "two levels up", is definitely not possible in the Bourne shell: the functions and command might run in a subshell, and such jump would have to be made across different processes.

But. The shell supports two features which are very useful for the testing: `set -e` and `set -o pipefail`.

`set -e` would cause the shell to stop script execution with non-zero status, if an unchecked command (actually: full command with pipes, `&&` and `||`) has exited with non-zero status.

`set -o pipefail` allows to abort script execution if a member of the pipeline exists with non-zero status. Normally, for pipes, the exit status of the last command is taken. Thus `set -e` is not sufficient, if you want to check all the processes in the pipe. The `set -o pipefail` closes the gap.

In `bash`, check output of `help set` to see the official description of the options. The man page has the full documentation.

P.S. Unwillingly, since nothing good ever came out of it:
You can achieve effect of macro programming in shell, using [the `eval` shell built-in](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#EVALREF).

Comment: Functions do not execute a subshell, unless they are explicitly defined to do so: `x=1; foo () ( x=3 ); echo $x` outputs 1, while `x=1; foo () { x=3; }; echo $x` outputs 3.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My problem was/is that I only wanted to return upon failure, not neccesassarily exit, since that would run the risk of killing the whole script, if the test isn't run in a subshell. Unless I'm missing something, `set` would exit rather than return upon failure. Maybe I'm being overly paranoid about exiting.

Comment: @parmsib You can always force something to run in a subshell by using `eval` or `()`. Just try it. Trying wouldn't hurt ;)

Comment: @chepner, "Functions do not execute a subshell" - way to nitpick - I never said they do. I said they *might run* in a subshell, which (disregarding pipes/etc) is a common practice in the testing: if the whole thing crashes, only subshell crashes, and you get a nice non-zero exit status for it.

Comment: So the take away here is it's common/good practice to use subshells (especially for testing), and that achieving what I'm after is hard/impossible without them.

Comment: @parmsib You can do it without subshells - but as you have noticed, it is much more typing. Compare `if false; return 1; fi` vs `set -e; false`. Anyway, it is not like subshells are something strange or remote: instead of `a_test_case` you simply write `( a_test_case )`.